# How to keep NULL values in STRING_SPLIT

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

Please excuse formatting, this is my first post.

I have a table like the one below:

| id | code | Fig |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | MB010@2-1-2-5A@2-2-3 |
| 2 | AAB | MB010@2-3-4-2@2-2A-2-4 |
| 3 | AABA | NULL |
| 4 | AAC | MB020@2-5-3A |

My code is as follows:

```
  SELECT 
     source.id
    ,source.code
    ,codePub = LEFT(source.Fig,5)
    ,f.value AS [FigRef]
  FROM [dbo].[sourceData] AS source
  OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(source.[Fig], '@') as f
  WHERE f.value NOT LIKE 'MB%'
```

Which gives me the following table:

| id | code | codePub | FigRef |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | MB010 | 2-1-2-5A |
| 1 | AAA | MB010 | 2-2-3 |
| 2 | AAB | MB010 | 2-3-4-2 |
| 2 | AAB | MB010 | 2-2A-2-4 |
| 4 | AAC | MB020 | 2-5-3A |

But I want the codes with NULL values as well, like below:

| id | code | codePub | FigRef |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | MB010 | 2-1-2-5A |
| 1 | AAA | MB010 | 2-2-3 |
| 2 | AAB | MB010 | 2-3-4-2 |
| 2 | AAB | MB010 | 2-2A-2-4 |
| 3 | AABA | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | AAC | MB020 | 2-5-3A |

How can I keep the codes with NULL Fig values?

Comment: I know you may not have any control here, but this is what we call a **broken** schema design. Correct design would handle this at INSERT/UPDATE time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause filters NULLs out.

`NULL LIKE 'MB%'` is "unknown", which is not "true" in the context of the `WHERE` clause, so these rows are filtered out.

`NULL NOT LIKE 'MB%'` is still "unknown", which is still not "true" in the context of the `WHERE` clause, so these rows are also filtered out.

`NULL = NULL` is "unknown", `NULL IS NULL` is "true".

[Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

> Comparison operators test whether two expressions are the same.
>
> The result of a comparison operator has the Boolean data type. This
> has three values: TRUE, FALSE, and UNKNOWN. Expressions that return a
> Boolean data type are known as Boolean expressions.
>
> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, an operator that has one or two NULL expressions returns UNKNOWN.

You need to explicitly compare with NULL using `IS` operator. For example, like this:

```
  SELECT 
     source.id
    ,source.code
    ,codePub = LEFT(source.Fig,5)
    ,f.value AS [FigRef]
  FROM 
      [dbo].[sourceData] AS source
      OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(source.[Fig], '@') as f
  WHERE 
      f.value NOT LIKE 'MB%' OR f.value IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be an easy as just putting isnull around the splitting values:

```
 SELECT 
     source.id
    ,source.code
    ,codePub = LEFT(source.Fig,5)
    ,f.value AS [FigRef]
  FROM [dbo].[sourceData] AS source
  OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(isnull(source.[Fig],'NULL'), '@') as f
  WHERE f.value NOT LIKE 'MB%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a union here:

```sql
SELECT 
    source.id,
    source.code,
    codePub = LEFT(source.Fig, 5),
    f.value AS [FigRef]
FROM [dbo].[sourceData] AS source
OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(source.[Fig], '@') AS f
WHERE f.value NOT LIKE 'MB%'

UNION ALL

SELECT id, code, Fig, NULL
FROM [dbo].[sourceData]
WHERE Fig IS NULL
ORDER BY id;
```